# Why do the type inference results differ for the intersection types?

Tags: typescript

I'm currently learning about intersection types in TypeScript and I have noticed that when there is a conflict in property types, the type inference results can be impacted by using different types.

```js
interface A {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface B {
  gender: string;
  age: boolean;
}

type D = A & B;  // D: never
```

```js
interface A {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface B {
  gender: string;
  age: string;
}

type D = A & B;  // D: A & B
```

Within the first code block, the type of D is inferred as `never`.

However, within the second code block, the type of D is inferred as `A & B`.

```js
//The A & B type
{
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  age: never;
};
```

Personally, I think that inferring `A & B` is a reasonable and expected result, but I still cannot understand why there are two distinct results by type inference.

TypeScript version 4.9.5

Comment: This is a result of [intersections reduced by discriminant properties](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties). The type `boolean` is shorthand for the union of literals `true | false` and therefore an acceptable discriminant property, whereas the type `string` is not a literal and therefore unacceptable, so `{a: boolean} & {a: number}` gets immediately reduced while `{a: string} & {a: number}` does not. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your response. According to the information you provided, I understand part of the behavior. However, `{a: string} & {a: number}` are also different types - why doesn't this cause `D` to be inferred as `never`? @jcalz

Comment: Not all impossible intersections are eagerly reduced to `never`. Before TS3.9, `{a: boolean} & {a: number}` was not reduced either. Support was added for reducing types involving *discriminated unions* because people wanted to filter them by intersections. Reducing intersections eagerly can break real world code (e.g., `keyof never` is `string | number | symbol` but `keyof ({a: string} & {a: number})` is "a"`), so it's not done universally. I can explain more if I write up an answer, which I'll only do if you acknowledge that I'm covering the question and not missing anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, I look forward to a more detailed response from you. @jcalz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the compiler does *not* aggressively or eagerly reduce object types with a [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)-valued property to `never` itself.  That's probably for the best, since such object types like this do appear in some real world code that uses type manipulation functions like mapped types, and also because it *is* possible to have values of these types, even if they're a bit contrived:

```
interface Foo {
  x: string;
  y: number;
  z: never;
}

const foo: Foo = {
  x: "abc",
  y: 123,
  get z(): never { throw new Error("GOTCHA!"); }
}

console.log(foo.x.toUpperCase()); // "ABC"
console.log(foo.y.toFixed(2)); // "123.00"
```

The point above is that a `never`-valued properly is harmless if you don't actually try to interact with that property.  It would have observable effects in the type system and break a lot of real world code if the compiler actively tried to enforce this.  (And if you go to the logical extreme, then any object with a method that throws should also be reduced to `never`).

So, on the face of it, that explains why the following [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) doesn't reduce:

```
interface A1 {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface B1 {
  gender: string;
  age: string;
}

type D1 = A1 & B1;  // D1: A1 & B1
```

Since `D1` is equivalent to `{name: string; age: never; gender: string;}`.

---

But wait, shouldn't that also mean that

```
interface A2 {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface B2 {
  gender: string;
  age: boolean;
}

type D2 = A2 & B2;  // D2: never
```

shouldn't reduce to `never`?  Well, this is different, because [the `boolean` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean) is actually shorthand for the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the two boolean [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `true | false`.  Indeed, anywhere you use `true | false` the compiler will display that type as `boolean`:

```
type Bool = true | false;
// type Bool = boolean
```

And therefore, the `age` property of `B2` can be used as the *discriminant* property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) (discriminants are usually *single* literal types, but the compiler lets you use other types too [as long it contains some literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants)).  Obviously this was not your intent when you wrote the `B2` type (although what you *did* intend by having a boolean age isn't clear ), but that's the way the language works.

TypeScript 3.9 introduced support for [reducing intersections by discriminant properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties).  And so, if you intersect an object type the compiler sees as a discriminant union with another object type, the compiler will aggressively reduce the intersection to `never` if the resulting discriminant property is of type `never`.   This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#36696](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696), and is responsible for the behavior where `D2` reduces to `never`; the `boolean`-valued `age` property is a discriminant, it becomes `never` when you intersect it with `number`, and thus the whole object type reduces to `never`.

Of course it is indeed possible to create a value of the unreduced type if the property in question throws when accessed, and it would be safe to do so if you don't inspect the `never`-valued property.  But since people use discriminated unions specifically with the intent of inspecting the discriminant property, this isn't a use case that's considered important to support.

---

So there you go, everything is behaving as designed and as intended.  If there is anything like a bug or design limitation here, it's that the heuristics for determining whether an object type is a discriminated union member are imperfect.  You never meant for `B2` to be a discriminated union member, so it's surprising when the compiler suddenly treats it differently in intersections from the superficially similar `B1`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAeAXMgM5hSgDmA3PsgJ6kgCuAtgEbT0EBeLCADceuAL65cCdCArIYmUhiwBeHAxLIARHE4ItAGgbNkARgBMAZiMFqEMMj4AKAJSCRUHMjAALKOgB3ZBAIIIBRKH8oJy0AcQB5ABUAYQAJAEEAQi0XWmQJCSkZMnQAGwgAOlL0aicFdArCCrB0AFUAB3boZLgyCFdc5AB6Ie10gCFkrSLZMsrq2vqKxmb0VGBCCAATJ3MXQZHtC0sKgAZT6dxQSFhEFHTTdQIQOHYIUgoqEDoGODsWDjcKD0QrXaDwJDIcaPPC2CAgLbQD6UGi8ZB-d7kFHfEGSMCMLrIAAijzUD2QADIoaY8sNRiTSOSqdDkJIwbdIelzE9gq9MZ9Ub9-sFAaJQeBwXcodzYcg7AikVivj8CBjSJxMOU4CBcbh8YSidyydzmeZaYdDe5oJI9QSUONNcg1JRWCgAD7yOClPr0Q76+2OtQaubaoA)